# CORONA: timer.cancel() returns "Attempt to index a nil value"

Tags: timer, lua, scope, null, coronasdk

I'm trying to cancel a timer started in a "touch event" function inside another "touch event" function, as shown below:

```
local function startNewGame(event)
if(event.phase=="ended")then
    local function animationImmaginiOggetti()
      for i=1, 7 do
        transition.to(immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i],
                      { time = 200, delay = 0, xScale = 0, yScale = 0, alpha = 0})
      end
    end
    local function removeImmaginiOggetti()
        if immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[1] then
            for i=1, 11 do
                immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i]:removeSelf()
                immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i] = nil
            end
        end
    end

    local tmrAIO = timer.performWithDelay(4000, animationImmaginiOggetti, 1)
    local tmrRIO = timer.performWithDelay(4250, removeImmaginiOggetti, 1)
end
end


local function replayGame(event)
    if(event.phase=="ended")then
        timer.cancel(tmrAIO)
        timer.cancel(tmrRIO)
    end
end

startBTN:addEventListener("touch", startNewGame)
replayBTN:addEventListener("touch", replayGame)
```

My problem is that Corona returns

> "File: ? `Attempt to index a nil value" on timer.cancel (tmrAIO)`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following, the variables `tmrAIO` and `tmrRIO` are local to the function `startNewGame`, that means they can only be accessed from the scope defined by `startNewGame` and right now you are trying to access both from outside that function and they are not defined in that scope that's why the `nil` value.

Solution:

```
local tmrAIO
local tmrRIO

local function startNewGame(event)
    if(event.phase=="ended")then
        local function animationImmaginiOggetti()
          for i=1, 7 do
            transition.to(immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i],
                          {time = 200, delay = 0, xScale = 0, yScale = 0, alpha = 0})
          end
        end
        local function removeImmaginiOggetti()
            if immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[1] then
                for i=1, 11 do
                    immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i]:removeSelf()
                    immaginiOggettiAvvioPartita[i] = nil
                end
            end
        end

        tmrAIO = timer.performWithDelay(4000, animationImmaginiOggetti, 1)
        tmrRIO = timer.performWithDelay(4250, removeImmaginiOggetti, 1)
    end
end

local function replayGame(event)
    if(event.phase=="ended")then
        timer.cancel(tmrAIO)
        timer.cancel(tmrRIO)
    end
end

startBTN:addEventListener("touch", startNewGame)
replayBTN:addEventListener("touch", replayGame)
```

As you can see I declared `tmrAIO` and `tmrRIO` outside of the scope of `startNewGame` making them accessible anywhere inside this file.

Comment: Can you mark it as answer, sorry to bother you this is my first time in stack overflow and I'm learning how this works :)