# Lua : timer.cancel --> 'Attempt to index a nil value'

Tags: timer, lua, composer-php, coronasdk, cancellation

I'm fairly new to Lua, and one particular command in my code has been causing me some major problems.

I've been trying to cancel the timer:

```
currentPuddleDelay = timer.performWithDelay(puddleDelay, createPuddle);
```

The error that I am shown is:

```
Attempt to index a nil value

File: ?

stack traceback:
?: in function 'cancel'
game.lua:534: in function '?'
?: in function 'dispatchEvent'
?: in function '_saveSceneAndHide'
?: in function 'gotoScene'
game.lua:452: in function '?'
?: in function <?:182>
```

From what I've researched already, this problem can occur when the timer is within a function and is local, however, the timer in my code is global, so I don't think that that is the problem.

Below is the bit of code with the issue:

```
local function createPuddle()
    local function constantDelay()

        local puddle = display.newImage( sceneGroup, "images/puddle.png" )
        puddle.x = puddleLane
        puddle.y = -200

        physics.addBody( puddle, "dynamic", {density=0, filter=puddleCollisionFilter} )
        puddle:applyForce( 0, puddleSpeed, puddle.x, puddle.y )
        sceneGroup:insert(3,puddle)

        local function onPuddleCollision( self, event )
            if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
                print('puddle collision')
                puddle:removeSelf( )
                puddle = nil
                composer.gotoScene( "menu" )
            end
        end
        puddle.collision = onPuddleCollision
        puddle:addEventListener( "collision" )
    end

    local constantDelayTimer = timer.performWithDelay(puddleDelay/2,constantDelay,1)
    currentPuddleDelayHold = timer.performWithDelay(puddleDelay, createPuddle);
end

currentPuddleDelay = timer.performWithDelay(puddleDelay, createPuddle);
```

And then later on in the program:

```
timer.cancel(currentPuddleDelay)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `currentPuddleDelay`? Are you sure it is accessible on the line where `timer.cancel()` is executed? Take a look at similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403817/corona-timer-cancel-returns-attempt-to-index-a-nil-value

Comment: Why are you setting `puddle = nil` inside `onPuddleCollision`? That will produce an "attempt to index a nil value" error if the same instance of `onPuddleCollision` is called twice with `event.phase == "began"` both times.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess as you most likely did not provide all relevant code.

It obviously doesn't make sense to cancel a non-existing timer so for the start just do

```
if currentPuddleDelay then timer.cancel(currentPuddleDelay) end
```

If there is any reason why currentPuddleDelay should still exist you should find out why it is nil.